# Ng Bootstrap Datepicker navigation

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I followed the example https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

```
    <div class="select-control date">
        <input class="form-control" 
               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
               navigation="select" 
               outsideDays="visible"
               name="dp" 
               [(ngModel)]="model" 
               ngbDatepicker
               #d="ngbDatepicker"
              (click)="d.toggle()"/>
    </div>
```

but im getting this

[image: Text]

instead of this

[image: Text]

What's wrong? any solution? i want to be able to navigate though months and years

PD: found the solution, install @angular/location

Comment: Hi @Sergi!
I just copy-pasted this code sample into stackblitz and I see the date picker with the navigation bar. The problem probably is not in this code sample. If you can provide stackblitz with the reproduction, we might be able to help.

Comment: yo! yeah, i was missing @angular/location, after i install, it worked :)

Comment: I was struggling until your post helped me identify the crazy one-off detail of needing to run "ng add @angular/localize" so the "import '@angular/localize/init';" is added to the polyfills.ts file. I can't believe this isn't something the npm install command can take care of. Cost me several hours. One would expect that a simple npm install @package would be enough to implement a few widgets. Thanks again for your clue. I wish you had mentioned the polyfills.ts file, though.

Comment: @Newclique agreed, that was a frustrating search. Thank you for posting that. 

This is definitely a bug in the datepicker; it should fall back gracefully if localization isn't detected. Instead it just deletes the header altogether.